# How do you customize Azure SQL Database to connect with a web application on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, connection, azure-sql-database

I am working on a website as a side project and currently I am trying to get my application to work with an Azure SQL database I have created. I have a login system that I used before in another website but I was not using Azure. I am sure my problem has to do something with with authentication when the application tries to access the database. I have connected the database to Visual studio and it is in the SQL Server Object Explorer.

[Picture of my database in the SQL Server Object Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHZT6.jpg)

When I run the application and try to login on my application it gives me the error number 18456 which is general SQL Authentication error. Here is the code of my login system:

[Initiation of Connection String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A04IM.jpg)

[Code behind login button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlJo5.jpg)

[Code behind login button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Eup.jpg)

[Connection string in App.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeRD9.jpg)

So I am very sure that there is a problem with either my connection string format or my firewalls on Azure.

I tried reading through a ton of Microsoft documentation and YouTube videos to solve the problem but nothing is making the error go away.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

> To connect your Azure SQL Database to your web application on Visual Studio, you have to configure the `connection string` in your application's configuration file. You can find the connection string in the Azure portal by navigating to your SQL Database and selecting the "Connection strings" option.

**SQL Server authentication**

[image]

**Connection string from Azure.**

[image]

**Connection String** for an Azure SQL Database

```
Server=tcp:<server-name>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<database-name>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<user-name>@<server-name>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tcp:rajtestsqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mytestdb11 DB;User ID=userid;Password=****"))
           {
              connection.Open();
              using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblSample VALUES (@Id,@Content)", connection))
               {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", fileContent);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
             }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
                        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

You can create tables using `Azure Data studio` or `Visual studio`.

[image]